# PHP: need to decode a string with utf chars embedded

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, decode

I have a string which is decoded as base36, ie 0-9a-z,
any other characters were decoded as follows: a unicode character code, converted to base36 and preceeded by capital letter 'A', and followed by letter 'B'.
If multiple unicode chars appear, only the last one if followed by 'B'.

Example:

```
zergme@wtfd-婴儿服饰.com
```

converted as:

```
zergmeA1sBwtfdA19Ahv8Ag1rAkctAub4A1aBcom
```

It was convenient to convert the data that way, but now I'm bashing my head on how to write a decode it back algorithm.

I already provided for a function that convert charcodes to the Unicode chars, which let be called 'unichr($code)';

...but I can't think of a good way finding these chars.

I was trying to use regexp first, something like:

```
preg_replace('/A.*?B?(?=[AB])/',"$1",$mail);
```

But it didn't work the way I wanted... And I also didn't realize how to cast my custom convertion function aka 'unichr()' on the matches.

Then I was also thinking about manually finding chars with strpos(), but it also turned out to be messy.

Could you advice some pattern? Or whether I should elaborate on regexp or try to use some loop? I'm kinda blank... Thanks :)

**LOLMAO**

That is it, Looks like I figured out, thanks to your contribution:

```
'/A(.*?)((?=A)|B)/'
```

Comment: 1. I'm not sure this is convertable just using regexp, you'll need a parser to scan the string, split by `[AB]` and process each encoded character separately. 2. If you want to encode new data, consider the punycode algorithm - both directions thereof are at least well-known.

Comment: Why dont you use UTF-8 encoding? It returns the string as: zergme%40wtfd-%E5%A9%B4%E5%84%BF%E6%9C%8D%E9%A5%B0.com. This can be decoded with Utf8 decoder. http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: well, I hope you realize it takes 6 chars foe each glyph, ie: %E5%A9 just one char. But for me it's twice less if convert to base62 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead? It takes a function instead of a string as the replace value, and will pass the matches to the function and use the function's return value as the replace string.

Loose example, you'll have to play around a bit

```
<?php
$str = 'zergmeA1sBwtfdA19Ahv8Ag1rAkctAub4A1aBcom';

function convert_to_unicode_cb( $match )
{
    // $match1 would be 1s, 19, hv8, etc
    return unichr( $match[1] );
}

preg_replace_callback( '/A(.*?)(?=A|B)/', 'convert_to_unicode_cb', $str );
```

Comment: Yeah, it's looks doable that way, you enhanced my knowledge on preg_callback func. Though it still doesn't work as you're capturing second group which also works as a separator. Adding non capturing group almost solves it: eg '/A(.*?)(?=A|B)/' but It still wouldn't help let me get rid of that B letter...

Comment: Ok, I see the problem with my original regex, but if you use a non-capturing second group it works fine for me. My callback is executed 7 times for the test string and `$match[1]` is equal to '1s', '19', 'hv8', 'g1r', 'kct', 'ub4', and '1a'

Comment: Yes, but did you realize the 'B' is then not getting captured, so the outcome would still contain letter 'B' :) I edited the question to what worked for me: it would then capture the 'B's but not to capture the second 'A'...

Answer (score 0):

How aobut Base64 encoding (gzcompress) and decoding (gzuncompress).

Save the following with the name "testBase64.php":

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text'])){
       echo("<b>input:</b> ".$_POST['text']."<br/>");
       $c = gzcompress($_POST['text']); 
       echo("<b>base64 encoding:</b> .".$c."<br/>");
       echo("<b>base64 decoding:</b> " .gzuncompress($c));
       exit;
    }
?>

<html>

    <body>
       <form method=post action=testBase64.php>
          <input type=text name=text />
          <input type=submit />
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Run and enter "zergme@wtfd-婴儿服饰.com" in the text field.

**Output:**

> **input:** zergme@wtfd-婴儿服饰.com
>
> **base64 encoding:** .xœ«J-JÏMu(/IKÑUS62645³Òæ–– ÚÌØÂH[YXë%ççG°@
>
> **base64 decoding:** zergme@wtfd-婴儿服饰.com

Hope this helps.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question. I considered many ways, and the way I convert data is convenient.